# Permissions problems for Apache2.2 on Solaris 11, setting a different DocumentRoot (RBAC issues?)

Tags: apache, permissions, solaris

I'm trying to set a different documentRoot in apache22 on Solaris 11.
I keep getting permissions problems.

The user webservd is owner/group on htdocs but when I su to webservd I can't read the dir.
No fancy ACLs there either.
I guess this is possibly to do with auths/roles/privileges but that is a bit out of my league.

I tried via documentRoot and also using VirtualHost:

```
Listen 8888

NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>

    DocumentRoot "/xxx/htdocs"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    ServerName  127.0.0.1
    ErrorLog "/var/apache2/2.2/logs/xxx_error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/apache2/2.2/logs/xxx_access_log" common

    <Directory "/xxx/htdocs">
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks  SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As far as I can tell apache .confs are fine but still no joy.
Any clues would be much appreicated!

Comment: verbatim error log message?

Comment: What are the permissions of both the `xxx` and the `htdocs` directories ? Owning `htdocs` is not sufficient for a user to access it.

Comment: sorry, not at work at the moment but from memory when I sudo to webservd and try to ls or anything to the htdocs (as in virtualHost) I get "permission denied". ..the apache error log also says permission denied, and not "denied by system" (as I think is the case with a "Deny" order in the .conf files.

the dir permissions are webservd:webservd 755 tried 777 also.
The default permissions in the default documentRoot /htdocs are root:bin 755. Default ACLs.